# Mongoose-Array empty even with populate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, model

I have this two models and I want to populate the array historico but even though I used the method populate the array is still empty. The reason I thinks think this is happening is because i didn´t specify the join parameter. How can I do it? In the find method or in the populate?

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  cartaoCidadao: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /[0-9]{8}/,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: ["password is a required field"] },
  historico: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Request",
    },
  ],
  role: { type: String },

  estado: { type: String, enum: ["Infetado", "Suspeito", "Curado"] },
});
```

```
var requestSchema = new Schema({
  paciente: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  encaminhado: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "encaminhado is a required field"],
    enum: ["Sim", "Não"],
  }, //vem do body
  pessoaRisco: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "pessoaRisco is a required field"],
    enum: ["Sim", "Não"],
  }, //vem do body
  trabalhoRisco: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "trabalhoRisco is a required field"],
    enum: ["Sim", "Não"],
  }, //vem do body
  estadoPedido: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Pendente", "Agendado", "Concluído", "Aguarda Resultado"],
  },
  resultado: { type: String, enum: ["Positivo", "Negativo"] },
  dataExame: { type: Date }, //data tem de ser superior a data atual
});
```

```
userController.getUserById = function (req, res, next, id) {
  User.findOne({ _id: id })
  .populate("historico")
  .exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      res.json(user);
    }
  });
};

userController.getOneUser = function (req, res) {
  res.json({
    cartaoCidadao: req.user.cartaoCidadao,
    historico: req.user.historico,
    estado: req.user.estado,
  });
};
```

Comment: `historico` should contain an array of ObjectIDs that `populate` will cross reference with the other collection.  See [saving refs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#saving-refs)

Comment: @Joe what do you mean?

Comment: We need to see some data in both tables. I have a feeling you actually don't have matching data